# How to remove the string href from the following associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've following array titled `$arr`:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
[url] =>  href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png"
        )
[1] => Array
        (
[url] =>  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf"        )
)
```

I don't want string href in the content I want following array :

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
[url] =>  http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png
        )
[1] => Array
        (
[url] =>  http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf        )
)
```

How should I do it?

Comment: why dont you use `str_replace` to replace the string..

Comment: Iterate array, fetch and replace value. Store them back to array.

Comment: @phpfresher:Ok I removed the href string. How to remove the double quotes around the URL string?

Comment: You can use an array inside `str_replace`... try this.. 
`str_replace(array('href=','"'),'',$str)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach ($array as $str) {
    $str = str_replace('href=','',$str);
}
```

EDIT:

You can use an array inside the `str_replace()` function. Like this:

```
foreach ($array as $str) {
    $str = str_replace(array('href=','"'),'',$str);
}
```

Comment: How to remove the double quotes put around the URL string?